# Convert a BST to sorted list

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, tree

The problem seems straight forward.
You must use the same tree and make the right child pointer as the next pointer in the list.

so the algorithm i used is as follows:

```
def inorder(node, prev, head):
        if(node == NULL):
            return;
        inorder(node.left, prev, head)

        node.right = prev
        if(!prev):
            head = node
        prev = node 

        inorder(node.right, prev, head)
```

can anyone point out where exactly i am going wrong because it just doesn't seem to work.

Comment: How does it not seem to work? What result do you expect that you're not getting?

Comment: Check this article out:
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/in-place-convert-a-given-binary-tree-to-doubly-linked-list/

Answer (score 1):

The first bug that I saw is that you're assigning to `head` and `prev` inside of `inorder` and are hoping that somehow this will affect `head` and `prev` inside of previous calls to `inorder`.  But it does not.

What you need to do instead is to have `inorder` return information that you want, then assign them within the parent call.